# On an infinite summation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

I was looking at this problem that can be found at the book "Experimental Mathematics" by Borwein.

Evaluate the series

$$\mathcal{S}= \sum_{\left ( m, n, p \right ) \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{ (0, 0, 0)\}} \frac{(-1)^{m+n+p}}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2+p^2}}$$

What techniques would one use to evaluate this ? I have no idea ! I can only assume that the final result may have a log in it and / or some zetas .

Comment: See the third problem here: http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/dhbpapers/tenproblems.pdf

Comment: Huh? Further beyond of what I was thinking ... ! \